# How do I make a counter to check, how many time a web page is reloaded by user using java script?

Tags: javascript, html

How do I make a counter to check, how many time a web page is reloaded  by user using java script? In this I want I static counter which is display on the screen and when any one close the browser and again load the page the counter should count after the last number ex before close 5 and after reloading it should be 6 not set to 0.

Comment: Do you want this counter to be user specific or to be a global counter for all users (they all share the same counter)

Comment: hello nick, i want to make it global not user spacific, just for only one page and practice purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage):

```
var counter = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("pageViews")) || 0;
counter++;
localStorage.setItem("pageViews", JSON.stringify(counter));
```

Comment: I don't think local storage will be good for a global counter. This is better for a user specific counter

Comment: @NickParsons That would require server-side code, or at least an AJAX request to update the page.

Comment: Yeah, and I think that OP wants a global counter instead of a user specifc counter ;)

Comment: yes, i just want a simple counter using only java script. we can use cookies, session any thing.

Comment: @Akshayvijayvargiya If you use sessions/cookies then the counter will belong to the user. In order to share the counter accross multiple users (like you said you wanted in the comments) you need to use server-side code like Jack mentioned in his comment above

Comment: @NickParsons so sir, can we make it for user spacific by using java script.

Comment: @Akshayvijayvargiya yeah, Jack's code will achieve a user specific counter for you :)